# nodejs discord get nickname from a users ID

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

My goals are to obtain the users nickname by using their ID.

Their ID's are stored as variables which are being collected from a reaction collector.
I have tried a few methods and failed, most of which either return nothing or errors.

The below code returns nothing, the getnames() function is empty.  This method was recommended to me buy 2 people from a nodejs discord server which aims to help solve issues, similar to here.

```
    // returns player ID's
    function getPlayers() {
            let players = [];
            players.push(queue.tank[0]);        // First (1) in TANK queue
            players.push(queue.heal[0]);        // First (1) in HEAL queue
            players.push(queue.dps[0]);         // First (2) in DPS queue
            players.push(queue.dps[1]);
            return players;
        }

    // get nick names from ID's
        function getnames() {
            let players = getPlayers();
            let playerNicks = [];
            let newPlayer = "";
            players.forEach(async player => {
            newPlayer = await message.guild.members.fetch(player).then(function (user) {return user.displayName });
            playerNicks.push(newPlayer)
            return playerNicks;
        })}

    //formats nicknames into string
        function formatnicknames() {
            let formatted_string2 = '';
            let playerNicks = getnames();

            if (playerNicks)
                formatted_string2 = `${playerNicks[0]} \n${playerNicks[1]} \n${playerNicks[2]} \n${playerNicks[3]}`;
            return formatted_string2;
        }
```

I have also tried a few variations of the below code, still unable to obtain nickname.

```
message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
```

Edit #1

now tried the following code with no success. (boost1ID contains the ID of 1 user)

```
var mem1 = message.guild.members.fetch(boost1ID).nickname
```

Edit #2

tried a new method of obtaining displayname from ID.

```
                    var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('guildid');
                    var mem1 = guild.member(boost1ID);
                    var mem2 = guild.member(boost2ID);
                    var mem3 = guild.member(boost3ID);
                    var mem4 = guild.member(boost4ID);
                    var nickname1 = mem1 ? mem1.displayName : null;
                    var nickname2 = mem2 ? mem2.displayName : null;
                    var nickname3 = mem3 ? mem3.displayName : null;
                    var nickname4 = mem4 ? mem4.displayName : null;

                    var Allnicknames = `${nickname1} ${nickname2} ${nickname3} ${nickname4}`
                    message.channel.send(`testing nicknames: ${Allnicknames}`)
```

I managed to only return my own name since i dont have a nickname on this server, but the other three users who does have a nickname returned null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest solution:

```js
// your users ids
const IDs = [ '84847448498748974', '48477847847844' ];

const promises = IDs.map((userID) => {
         return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
              const member = message.guild.member(userID) || await message.guild.members.fetch(userID);
              resolve(member.displayName || member.user.username);
         });
});

const nicknames = await Promise.all(promises);
// you now have access to ALL the nicknames, even if the members were not cached!
```

The members you are trying to get the nicknames of are not necessarily cached, and this fixes that.

Comment: It seems that it also works good if I type `member.nickname` instead of `member.displayName`

Answer (score 0):

I made an example that could help you.

```
let testUsers = [];

module.exports = class extends Command {
  constructor(...args) {
      super(...args, {
         description: 'Testing.',
         category: "Information",
     });
 }

async run(message) {
    
    function getNicknames(userArr, guild) {
        let playerNicks = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < userArr.length; i++) {
            playerNicks.push(guild.member(userArr[i]).displayName);
        }
        return playerNicks;
    }
    let testUser = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);
    testUsers.push(testUser);
    let guild = message.guild;
    console.log(getNicknames(testUsers, guild));
    
    

 }
}
```

I created a function `getNicknames` that takes in two parameters. The first one is an Array of users (as you get one from your function `getPlayers()`) and the second one is the guild you are playing in. You need to provide the guild, because every user should be a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), because you want to use `.displayName`.  I created a user Array outside of my command code, because otherwise there will only be one user in the Array everytime you use the command. Inside of the `getNicknames()` function I have created a new Array `playerNicks` that I basically fill with the user nicknames we get from our provided user Array.

Now you have to implement that into your code.
The call of the function `getNicknames()`, for your code should look like this:

```
getNicknames(getPlayers(), message.guild);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, ive tried adding this to my code but it leaves me with some unreachable code. Also it wont allow me to use getPlayers function within the getNicknames function. (I am fairly new to coding in general, I understand enough to get by, but totally lost here lol). Ive tried a few other ways of obtaining displayName from ID. Ill edit my original post for you to see if you would like.

Comment: @Ben what if you change all the nickname variables in your edit #2 into `var nickname1 = mem1.displayName;` and so on?